# How to loop through a multidimenional array through pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, pointers

Looping through a simple array is no problem, but what is the correct way to loop through the multidimentional array by using pointers?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int data1[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for(auto *p = data1; p!=data1+9; ++p)
    {
        std::cout << (*p) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    int data2[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

    for(auto *lineP = data2; lineP!=data2+3; ++lineP)
    {
        for(auto *p = &(lineP[0]); p!= &(lineP[3]); ++p)
        {
            std::cout << (*p) << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In here `data1` is looped through correctly producing the expected output. But `data2` loop is wrong in some way, because the output is not the values of the elements, but rather the addresses.

Example output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0x7ffde45b77a0 0x7ffde45b77ac 0x7ffde45b77b8 
0x7ffde45b77ac 0x7ffde45b77b8 0x7ffde45b77c4 
0x7ffde45b77b8 0x7ffde45b77c4 0x7ffde45b77d0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given: int mdArray[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

- mdArray is a pointer to a 3 element array
- each element in that array is a pointer to a 3 element array
- each element in those arrays is an integer

So just nest your original syntax inside itself substituting the de-referenced var instead of the name of the multidimensional array itself

```
    int mdArray[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    
    for(auto *d1 = mdArray; d1 != (mdArray + 3); d1++)
    {
      for(auto *d2 = *(d1); d2 != (*(d1) + 3); d2++)
      {
        std::cout << *(d2) << ' ';
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> for(auto *p = &(lineP[0]); p!= &(lineP[3]); ++p) {
> std::cout << (*p) << ' ';
> }

Should be

> for(auto p = &(lineP[0]); p!= &(lineP[3]); ++p) {
> std::cout << (*p) << ' ';
> }

Be aware of auto p. You asked a pointer of an adress. You made à pointer pointer.
Then dereference it, the result is adress, not value.

You could also cout **p